# Full mess with bluetooh headset - 14.04

Tags: sound, 14.04, bluetooth, headphones

I've got a brand new bluetooth headphone [Philips SHB7150](http://www.p4c.philips.com/cgi-bin/dcbint/cpindex.pl?slg=en&scy=fr&ctn=SHB7150FB/00) with a brand new Belkin bluetooth adapter V4.

The pairing is fine but after i cannot get the newly discovered headset in my pulseradio.

Instead I get the following image [image] with erratic behavior when trying to use the bluetooh headset.

Comment: I don't speak french, but I do have a Bluetooth headset and I don't see anything wrong in the screenshot. Please describe the erratic behaviour.

Comment: The erratic behaviour happens as following : when I select the headphone set, I'm not always able to use it as the sound output. It sometimes switch to internal speakers without any further message. I tried pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover but this will only run once.

Comment: That sounds to me like an issue with the Bluetooth adpater (maintaining or establishing a connection). You should try another adapter. (http://www.amazon.de/dp/B003ZDW78C/ works fine with my Fidelio M1BT, it has the same ID on amazon.fr but worse rating. Also branding doesn't seem to matter as most if not all of these apdapters chips are made by CSR, which also owns [aptX](http://askubuntu.com/q/425333/40581).)

Comment: The result is the same with two different adapters : One Trust V3.0 adapter and a brand new Belkin V4.0 adapter. To my opinion 10.04 is not mature enough to handle bluetooth properly

Comment: Moreover I do not see the headset in the list until I issue the command "pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover". I really do not know what this command is meant for.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea about it ? I cannot imagine nobody has faced the same problem

Comment: Does not for me in the same configuration. problem re-occurs ...

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug that is already [repored](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1283003).

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug reported in Gramic message.

It seems to be fixed after Bluetooth updates.

Works fine with a Belkin V4.0 USB Bluetooth adapter.

Comment: Does not for me in the same configuration. problem re-occurs