# How to enable AptX for Bluetooth devices?

Tags: bluetooth

The answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425333/how-to-make-aptx-capable-bluetooth-equipment-work-with-ubuntu/425334#425334) doesn't go over HOW to enable AptX if you have a compatible AptX dongle.

Comment: Hello  Seltonu, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do is ask a question; you should edit your post and actually include a question. You should also clarify the context: who gives that error message? When does it give that error message? What are you doing in order to make that error message appear? Is the error message unexpected?

Answer (score 13):

Since I can not mark this as a duplicate:

The accepted answer to the linked question added the answer to this "question" as well. The linked github project https://github.com/EHfive/pulseaudio-modules-bt adds support to pulseaudio for aac, aptx, aptx hd and ldac codecs.

Due to licensing issues, it can not be merged upstream. However, an Ubuntu ppa is supplied:
https://github.com/EHfive/pulseaudio-modules-bt/wiki/Packages#ubuntu-1804-1810-1904

## For future reference:

First the PPA needs to be installed. This can be done with the following for Ubuntu 18.04, 18.10, 19.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eh5/pulseaudio-a2dp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libavcodec58 libldac pulseaudio-modules-bt
```

If you have newer Ubuntu versions, instead, the correct code is the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:berglh/pulseaudio-a2dp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseaudio-modules-bt libldac
```

Now you need to restart pulseaudio:

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

I then had to reconnect my headphones (Sennheiser HD 4.50 BTNC), and set them as audio sink. In the sound settings, AptX was already displayed. Selecting AAC/AptXHD/LDAC didn't change what was used (due to my headphones only supporting AptX).
To check on the shell:

```
pactl list sources | grep a2dp_codec
```

The above has no output when used without the custom modules!

Answer (score 2):

For those seeing this n 2023 Aptx support has been added to PulseAudio in version 15.0 as well as ldac support and both codecs should work out of the box on the current Ubuntu release. Here is the link to the PulseAudio 15.0 release notes.
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Notes/15.0/