# No AptX HD over BT even after installing pulseaudio-modules-bt

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

Running Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS.

I have followed all the steps illustrated in [ArchimedesMP's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1173550/146804) to [How to enable AptX for Bluetooth devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071469/how-to-enable-aptx-for-bluetooth-devices).

I have an HD AptX compatible device (Audioengine B1) which should be able to receive HD audio over BT. I am definitely able to do so on Windows and also when I stream music from my phone.

I made sure I selected pulse audio as the audio engine in the audio mixer (A2DP Sink is actually the only option there, should it show AptX here, perhaps?) as well as in the audio player I am using (I tried Strawberry, Guayadeque and Rhythmbox).

`sudo hcidump avdtp` only returns the following:

```
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 5.53
device: hci0 snap_len: 1500 filter: 0x400
```

Before installing `pulseaudio-modules-bt` I could actually see the program "sniffing" the packets over the Bluetooth connection.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to use the ppa myself on 20.04. However, note that the packages in the ppa are outdated, the latest Ubuntu version is Disco. When trying with "disco" in repository sources, I can install but cannot connect to the BT headphones (the switch in the connection dialog is immediately reset), which works with the default pulseaudio-module-bluetooth. 
I also get the same dump output as you, nothing else.

I suppose an incompatibility with the outdated ppa packages. I will compile from git one of these days, 
https://github.com/EHfive/pulseaudio-modules-bt