# What is the state of aptX in Ubuntu 20?

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio

Over the last years I have followed the development around low latency and high quality codecs on bluetooth headphones. To be short: They are popular and the most used codec seems to be aptX.

That brings me to my questions:

- **Is ubuntu 20 capable of aptX?**
- **Do I still need to [recompile pulseaudio](https://github.com/droidman/aptx-for-ubuntu)?**

Theres also [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425333/how-to-make-aptx-capable-bluetooth-equipment-work-with-ubuntu) on this topic but it was authored in 2014

Comment: the gihub link is not working. can you update it, please?
did you able to find a solution?

Comment: Im sorry @Kostanos github user droidman decided to delete his repository. I also have no backup and it was not cached on archive.org. Compiling EHfive's pulseaudio-modules-bt or buying additional hardware seem to be the only choices right now.

Answer (score 2):

#### The Good News

The latest PulseAudio includes support for aptX. This is [version 15.0](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Notes/15.0/#supportforldacandaptxbluetoothcodecsplussbcxqsbcwithhigher-qualityparameters) released on 2021-07-27.

> **Support for LDAC and AptX bluetooth codecs, plus "SBC XQ" (SBC with higher-quality parameters)**
>
> PulseAudio now supports the LDAC and AptX codecs for A2DP. In order to use them (...)

#### The Bad News

Ubuntu 20.04 is running version 13.99.1.

```
$ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 13.99.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The original creator was no longer able to maintain the PPA he had for supporting this. Someone else took over managing a PPA using the original creator's sources.

[https://launchpad.net/~berglh/+archive/ubuntu/pulseaudio-a2dp](https://launchpad.net/%7Eberglh/+archive/ubuntu/pulseaudio-a2dp)

If you run into any issues, here is the github issue that tracked this work - https://github.com/EHfive/pulseaudio-modules-bt/issues/85#issuecomment-618870211.

Hope this helps!

Comment: so from that first link i see to run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:berglh/pulseaudio-a2dp;
sudo apt-get update`  but it's not clear what I need to actually do *after* that... apt-get something, presumably, but what? Is it the same set of steps in the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071469/how-to-enable-aptx-for-bluetooth-devices?rq=1)?

Comment: @Michael yes, that appears to work

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 21.10 will include pulseaudio 15

pulseaudio  1:15.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu2
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth 1:15.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu2
pulseaudio-utils    1:15.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu2