# After removing pulseaudio-modules-bt my headphones get disconnected every time

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I wanted to listen to AptX sound, because of that I installed pulseaudio-modules-bt. It didn't work and I removed it. Now after turning bluetooth on, off, unparing my headphones, removing them from my list of devices,.. I still can't get them to connect permanently.

The headphones just connect for one second, then they get disconnected. I am not able to see them in the list of the pulseaudio devices.

Is there a way to reset all the things bluetooth related in Ubuntu and pulseaudio? My /etc/bluetooth/main.conf is set to default values.

//edited:

it is from this repo: http://ppa.launchpad.net/berglh/pulseaudio-a2dp/ubuntu

as mentioned here: [How to enable AptX for Bluetooth devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071469/how-to-enable-aptx-for-bluetooth-devices)

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: A package named `pulseaudio-modules-bt` does not exist in the [Ubuntu repos for any recent version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pulseaudio-modules-bt&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), do you mean the package `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`? Which version of Ubuntu do you use? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1306216/edit) your question to add details.

Answer (score 0):

1. pulseaudio-module-bt is already deprecated as of now, see github page for more information;
2. You will have to manually install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth to connect Bluetooth audio devices;
3. AptX is currently not officially supported by pulseaudio, you will have to look elsewhere;

(pulseaudio-module-bt will still work with aptx and ldac if you don't mind using deprecated software, lmk if you are interested in that route)

**EDIT**: 
Setting up pulseaudio-module-bt (deprecated):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:berglh/pulseaudio-a2dp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseaudio-modules-bt libldac
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

Unpair Bluetooth audio devices; 
Restart Bluetooth; 
Re-pair Bluetooth audio devices; 
Settings /Sound/Output/Output-Device, select your device; 
Settings /Sound/Output/Configuration, select your codec;

Comment: pulseaudio-module-bt is already installed. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Mathem see edits