# Is it possible to use aptx when using my Pc as a Bluetooth sink/receiver?

Tags: bluetooth, streaming, codecs, a2dp

Connecting my phone via Bluetooth to my pc and enabling a2dp streaming from my phone to my pc is easy to do. (Bluetooth 5.0)
But there always is a average codec used making the loss of quality quite big.
Since the hardware should support it (I suppose) is it possible to use aptx in this setup?

Comment: This Q/A may help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425333/how-to-make-aptx-capable-bluetooth-equipment-work-with-ubuntu